# How to recreate slanted logotype?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to recreate this logo (of course, no one has the source file.

[image]

I'm struggling with the type where it says HAWKS. I can't find an easy way to have the logotype increase in size and fill a parralellogram-like shape.

I tried using the envelope distort tool, but the text gets really wavy.

It seems like there is an easy way to do this, that I'm not aware of. Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the text outlined, can you not just use the free transform - free distort tool?

[image]

I dont have the exact Font but This was just a quick try at it. You could even individually transform the letters to make them better fit.

Comment: I was trying to not individually transform the letters, as it's prone to inconsistencies. I was hoping there is a better solution, but I could always fall back to this technique.

Comment: You could also make the entire rectangle with words on inside with shadow. Then free distort the entire shape.

Comment: this turned out to be the best way to go. i put in some slanted guides at the top and bottom which helped the letters to be consistent when I was transforming them.